# Can not build Xamarin IOS Solution

Tags: ios, xamarin.android, azure-pipelines

I have a `VSTS Xamarin` build which includes both "`Install an Apple certificate`" and "`Install an Apple provisioning profile`". These tasks are succeeding completely but "`Build Xamarin.iOS solution **/*.sln`" failing with error

> Could not find any available provisioning profiles for iOS

Please help me to rectify the error

Comment: Which build agent did you use? Could you share the whole build log?

Comment: The logs are with customer and I dont have previllage to share them.But the agent is Hosted Mac OS Preview

Comment: Could you share your build definition? How did you install the provisioning profile?